# Postman collection to jmeter script - unable to convert API tests

Tags: jmeter, postman

[image]

I am having a collection having the shown API. When I convert this API using loadium it not converting it's tests to assertions. is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a tool which will analyze the custom code you produced using [Postman API](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/) as you can create arbitrary crazy logic there so you can get HTTP Request samplers but not the assertions.

You will have to add [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) or [JSON Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion) or if you prefer keeping assertion logic as the code - [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial/) but unfortunately there is no automated way of converting Postman assertions to JMeter ones as of now.

Answer (score 1):

In JMeter here is what you can do:

- Use Recording Template: Menu File > Templates... > Select recording template and confirm
- Go to HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder element and click on start button

If Postman uses HTTPs add the JMeter certificate generated in jmeter/bin folder to Postman keystore or disable [SSL Verification](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/#certificate-data).

In Postman configure the proxy to point to JMeter which listens on:

- Host:localhost
- Port:8888

Run your Postman script and it will be recorded in JMeter